# Google-apps script: Remove rows with strings in getValues

Tags: google-apps-script

I use a function which check the length of a column and insert unique-id's in each cell.

```
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var dataincol = sh.getRange(1,8,sh.getMaxRows(),1).getValues(); //getRange row, column, numRows, numColumns
//thanks to Serge insas
```

My problem is that the getValues() also takes strings, what I dont intend, and I dont know how to filter strings from my Range. The dataincol should take only free cells, ignoring strings and continue with the increase of the numbers.

Here you can see the full function:

```
function fillRowNumber(){
  var col = 1 ; // this for column A ! change to your needs
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataincol = sh.getRange(1,col,sh.getMaxRows(),1).getValues();
  var maxval =0
  for(n=0;n<dataincol.length;++n){
    if(Number(dataincol[n][0])>maxval){ maxval=Number(dataincol[n][0])}
    }
  for(n=1;n<sh.getLastRow();++n){
    if(dataincol[n-1][0] == ''){ dataincol[n-1][0]=maxval+1;++maxval}
    }
  sh.getRange(1,col,sh.getMaxRows(),1).setValues(dataincol);
}
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: I don't understand your question... you show *var dataincol = sh.getRange(1,8,sh.getMaxRows(),1)* but the "8" should be replaced by col to choose which column you want to check.

Comment: i too think i don't understand the question. my answer below may be wholly wrong or just what the doc ordered. difficult to tell. The question title doesn't seem to relate to the problem at hand ... or does it?

Comment: The 8 stands for a col in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two number validations I often use are: `parseInt(val) == val` which is a value check and `val.toString().match(/[0-9\-\.]/i) > -1)` which a string check.

In the code below, instead of double for{} loops I have used array functions. For loops works just as well, I just prefer the array functions in EC5.

First builds an array just of numerical values in the column (with indexes preserved in case you want to use this for anything else down the line - alternative is to filter out non-numeric values)

Second amends dataincol to fill in blanks with incremented maxval.

```
function fillRowNumber(){
  var col = 1;
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataincol = sh.getRange(1, col, sh.getMaxRows(), 1).getValues();
  var maxval = 0;

  var map = dataincol.map(function(row) { 
    // fill an array with numbers where numbers exist in data otherwise 0
    return (parseInt(row[0],10) == row[0]) ? row[0] * (row[0].toString().match(/[0-9\-\.]/i) > -1) : 0;
  });

  maxval = Math.max.apply(Math, map); // Mathmatical maximum

  dataincol = dataincol.map(function(row, index) { 
    if (row[0] == '') {
      maxval += 1; // increment maximum value
      // if blank cell then add new maximum value
      return (row[0] == '') ? [maxval] : [row[0]]; // if you add [&& index < sh.getLastRow()] to the conditional it restricts it to the original range of used cells not the maximum
    } else {
      // leave cell intact
      return [row[0]];
    }
  });

  sh.getRange(1, col, sh.getMaxRows(), 1).setValues(dataincol);
}
```

I wasn't clear if you wanted to keep adding maximum values for the whole sheet or just within the bounds of originally entered data. Try the alternative I note in the code comment `line 18`